# SSL Certificate unable to get local issuer certificate php background script

Tags: php, ssl

How to solve certificate problem on php background script? The script works if I   load it directly in the browser but it isn't working when calling it from `system` like so:

```
system ("php somescript.php");
```

It returned fatal error in console:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException: cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Bit of a Guess, but maybe the PHP CLI does not have access to that certificate store

Comment: I've set the environment variable for the correct PHP version. The one running the script is the same with the one running in wampserver.

Answer (score 1):

This is a rather unhelpfully-worded error that the Openssl library logs when it can't or doesn't know how to access the CA certificates on the system, or when it encounters a server/client whose certificate is not signed by a CA it trusts.
Openssl is typically compiled with default CA directory and/or path with the options --configure-ca-path and --configure-ca-bundle.
Check that this is the case for your installation (it most likely is) and that the CA directories do exist and can be read from by your script. 
If your script provides its own CA bundle as a replacement for the default ones, also check that the path is correct.
Finally, everything may be set up correctly, in which case the remote certificate's CA isn't trusted by Openssl (since it's not in the list of trusted CAs). In this case you simply have to handle the exception or fix the trust issue, either locally by adding the remote's CA to the bundle or remotely by changing the certificate to one that's trusted.

Comment: how to check for --configure-ca-path and --configure-ca-bundle?